# Explicit locking mechanism in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I did not find explicit sqlite locking commands before inserting or updating rows into the table. Does sqlite handle the locking mechanism on it own? 
The pager module described in http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html handles the locking mechanism. But I am not sure if there are any commands that the user can use to explicitly lock the tables. Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

As far as I know there are no dedicated sqlite commands to control locking.  However you can get sqlite to lock the database using [create transaction](https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).  For instance:

```
BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION;
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

If you read the documentation I linked you should get a better idea on the difference between `IMMEDIATE` & `EXCLUSIVE` transactions.

It might be worth noting that the locks in sqlite apply to the whole database and not just individual tables, unlike the `LOCK TABLE` statement in other sql databases.

Answer (score 13):

SQLite does whatever locking is necessary in order to implement the transaction scheme that your SQL statements describe. In particular, if you don't describe any then you get auto-commit behavior, with a lock held for the duration of each statement and then dropped as the statement finishes. Should you need longer transactions (often true!) then you ask for them explicitly with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` (often shortened to `BEGIN`) and finish with `COMMIT TRANSACTION` (or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`). The transaction handling is frequently wrapped for you by your language interface (as this makes it considerably easier to get right, coupling the transaction lifetime to a code block or method call) but at the base level, it comes down to `BEGIN`/`COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK`.

In short, you've got transactions. Locks are used to *implement* transactions. You don't have raw locks (which is a good thing; they're rather harder to get right than you might think from first glance).