# Multiple access to database. How to prevent separate threads from modifying the same data?

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, locking

The app will be installed on up to 10 machines, one of them will function as a server as well. One same DataGridView, permanently synchronized with the server will be opened on all of them. Different "users" will have different modifying access etc. For example, all of them will be able to delete rows in the table but only those who created a row, will be able to modify it etc.
I am currently using a SQLite on a server. Obviously, I'll need to connect clients with the server using C#-s socket connection abilities.
The problem is, that at some point, one of the clients will try to access (for example to delete) a row that is being modified by another client at the moment. This may cause a lot of issues. As far as I could understand, there is a technique called database locking and , which gives you the ability to limit client access to database.
My question is:
Will it be convenient to lock a database while the changes are made? For example, the function that will try to access a database will try to do that again and again (in a kind of a loop), until it sees that it can modify the database. Will that work?
Is there any better solution?
Maybe some other databases provide something resembling query stacking for multiple access?

Don't know if I'm making myself clear. If any other information is required in order for this question to be understandable, please comment.

Comment: Don't know about SQLite, but most databases have concurrency issue mitigation (usually with row locks).  You can also implement a lock block in your code, or look into more customizable use with the Semaphore class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters (because I saw this in the MySQL tag) here's the relevant MySQL manual page : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html , in this case simply doing

```
LOCK TABLES someTableName WRITE;
...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

With SQLite specifically I found this SO question [Explicit locking mechanism in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956475/explicit-locking-mechanism-in-sqlite) , taking that example you'd be looking at something like

```
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION;
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

However it also mentions that will lock the whole database and not just the tables in question.  The link included in that answer for the SQLite documentation is http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Overall it sounds a bit as if SQLite may not be the best database for you to be using as locking the entire database could create quite a bottleneck.  If viable it may be worth investigating another DB server such as MySQL which is better able to cope.