# SQL Select row, Update that row, No race conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

Right now I am running two queries but there is a race condition when running concurrently. How can I rewrite this without a race condition while still knowing which row was updated?

sqlite3 https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API

```
    SELECT * FROM pages WHERE domain=? ORDER BY crawled ASC LIMIT 1;
    UPDATE pages SET crawled=DATETIME('now') WHERE id=?;
    ... use results from SELECT query ...
```

Comment: In all rdbms you use transactions to group commands together then commit or rollback at the end. Then lock the rows in the select statement with the `for update` clause. Alas, this is not possible in SQLite ;-/. Instead you can use the `begin immediate transaction`, It is all explained here: [Explicit locking mechanism in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956475/explicit-locking-mechanism-in-sqlite)

Comment: i gave up. sqlite is a pain to work with. postgres just works